# How to create external Hive table without location?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-hive

I have a spark sql 2.1.1 job on a yarn cluster in cluster mode where I want to create an empty external hive table (partitions with location will be added in a later step).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (id BIGINT, StartTime TIMESTAMP, EndTime TIMESTAMP) PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```

When I run the job I get the error:

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE must be accompanied by LOCATION

But when I run the same query on Hive Editor on Hue it runs just fine. I was trying to find an answer in the SparkSQL 2.1.1 documentation but came up empty.

Does anyone know why Spark SQL is more strict on queries?

Comment: Just use the root folder of the table or any arbitrary location for that matter

Comment: P.s. there is no such thing as a table without location. If you haven't define a location then a default path is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** `EXTERNAL` with no `LOCATION` [is not allowed](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkSqlParser.scala#L1095-L1096).

The definitive answer is in Spark SQL's grammar definition file [SqlBase.g4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4).

You can find the definition of `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` as [createTableHeader](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L216):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY? EXTERNAL? TABLE (IF NOT EXISTS)? tableIdentifier
```

This definition is used in the supported SQL [statements](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L75-L87).

Unless I'm mistaken `locationSpec` is optional. That's according to the ANTLR grammar. The code may decide otherwise and it seems it does.

```
scala> spark.version
res4: String = 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT

val q = "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (id BIGINT, StartTime TIMESTAMP, EndTime TIMESTAMP) PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'"
scala> sql(q)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Operation not allowed: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE must be accompanied by LOCATION(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table (id BIGINT, StartTime TIMESTAMP, EndTime TIMESTAMP) PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT, day INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
^^^

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.operationNotAllowed(ParserUtils.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitCreateHiveTable$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:1096)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitCreateHiveTable$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:1064)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitCreateHiveTable(SparkSqlParser.scala:1064)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitCreateHiveTable(SparkSqlParser.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$CreateHiveTableContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:1124)
  at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:71)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(AstBuilder.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:68)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:623)
  ... 48 elided
```

The default `SparkSqlParser` (with `astBuilder` as `SparkSqlAstBuilder`) has the [following assertion](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkSqlParser.scala#L1095-L1096) that leads to the exception:

```
if (external && location.isEmpty) {
  operationNotAllowed("CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE must be accompanied by LOCATION", ctx)
```

---

I'd consider reporting an issue in [Spark's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK/) if you think that the case should be allowed. See [SPARK-2825](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2825) to have a strong argument to have the support:

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE already works as far as I know and should have the same semantics as Hive.